# Can I use the Mono Framework and .NET Core on the same machine?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I want to code games in Unity, but also want to make some apps with .Net Core.So, do I have to reinstall visual studio  every time I want to switch between the two?

Comment: I  am using a Mac.

Comment: Why would you think you can't have both installed on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just like you can have multiple versions of .net installed

Comment: As BugFinder said - just remember to switch the correct version when starting a new project. I recently made the mistake where I made a game server + client both in .NET 6 but the client had to be in Framework 4.8

Answer (score 0):

I think it's OK, as long as unity is associated with visual studio, the specific steps are: Edit→preference→External Tools→External Script Editor, find the visual studio installation path and configure it